# shader=faceted interp does not compile in Xelatex

Tags: pgfplots, xetex

I am using pgfplots

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=\linewidth]
        \addplot3[surf, mesh/cols=41,mesh/ordering=colwise,faceted color=black,shader=faceted interp] table {P.dat};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

my P.dat is here:
http://pastebin.com/xdevrCNF

Note that the same code compiles if I omit the shader directive

Comment: Also, what backend are you using, `pdftex`, `luatex`?

Comment: I am using xelatex and I am getting the following error            `! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \
l.355     \end{axis}`

Comment: I am currently updating my distribution and will check it out again

Comment: Still the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the xetex driver of `pgfplots`. Apparently, the bug does not show up for `shader=interp` although it is present as well (pollutes log file, I guess).

I have fixed it in the developer version of `pgfplots`.

That means you have the following options:

1. wait a couple of days until I have updated the unstable revision on http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/ and install that one or
2. wait for the next stable of `pgfplots` and upgrade or
3. use `shader=interp` or
4. use a hotfix patch, see below.

Here is the hotfix: write

```
\makeatletter
\let\pgfplotssys@do@surfshading@fillpaths@@@=\pgfplotssys@do@surfshading@fillpaths
\def\pgfplotssys@do@surfshading@fillpaths#1{%
    \let\pgfplots@loc@TMPb=\relax
    \pgfplotssys@do@surfshading@fillpaths@@@{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

into the preamble of your document and the problem is gone.

Comment: Indeed it compiles ok with pdflatex. But it seems that the pdf renders slowly in the page of the graph. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: This is a weakness of `faceted interp`. The issue along with potential alternatives is discussed in the manual in the documentation of the `patchplots` library; the section is called  "Drawing Grids".